# Android toast not showing inside onDestroy of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-toast

My requirement is when user swipes(destroys) my application from Recent tab, I want to show a toast.
For this I tried showing the toast in `onDestroy` of the MainActivity, But the toast does not show up. I am using the following code :

`Toast.makeText(this, "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Can you help what could be the reason?

Comment: it should be onTabChanged

Comment: You should post the code else this would be just a guess work. Well, my guess: Put the toast before **super.onDestroy()**

Comment: I used to show toast before super.onDestroy.. But no help.
There is not much code here.. I just show a toast on onDestroy of activity.
Scenario is :
When my application is running, some background service is started and the work is being done. Now when my application is destroyed from recents page, I kill my process in onDestroy of MainActivity. Now before killing my process, I want to show a toast to user say like "service is stopped"

Answer (score 1):

The context becomes null so the Toast does not appear. You may put a log to see whether the code is executed on that line or not.

Comment: I already added a log. and the above line of code is executed

Comment: It is difficult to show Toast while the app destroys from the background. Can you please share what you want to do ?

Comment: When my application is running, some background service is started and the work is being done. Now when my application is destroyed from recents page, I kill my process in onDestroy of MainActivity. Now before killing my process, I want to show a toast to user say like "service is stopped"

Comment: Just override the "onTaskRemoved" from Service classs which is called when the service is running and the user remove it from the backgroud. Now put the toast inside "onTaskRemoved" like -    Toast.makeText(this, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 0):

you can write this code and see logcat

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("OnDestroy", "onDestroy: OnDestroy called");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Toast only shows up in onDestroy(), when you have called super.onBackPressed() either in onBackPressed() or in the beginning of onDestroy(). For example:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(false);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You're offline!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    super.onDestroy();
}
```